# Why is Breit reference frame called "infinite momentum frame"?

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, reference-frames, conservation-laws, collision

In particle physics, the reference frame in which the incoming particle bounces off with opposite velocity as if hitting a wall (the Breit frame, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breit_frame) is also called "infinite momentum frame". Why is it so? I do not see any infinite in there.